# Following URLS in backbone.js on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have started to get familiar with backbone.js and needed a little time to wrap my head around routers, models and views.

Handling routes through router and defining them are piece of cake, until that particular route is defined as `<a href="#some-url">` (I am not sure 100%, but I presume backbone is overriding default link behavior and instead redirecting it dynamically load templates staying on current page).

What I need is acton that is executed on user clicking on div element. It was easy to add event under view, and clicking on the div correctly called the function.

But from that point I was uncertain what to do. I can easily add:  `window.location.href = "#some-url"`, and browser will redirect page to asked href, but that seems as breaking one-pager rules backbone is trying to create.

Is there a more appropriate way to handle views change than forcing browser to change href via window.location ?

EDIT: added the code.

app.js

```
require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'app/router'], function ($, Backbone, Router) {
    window.router = new Router();   
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

app/router.js

```
var $           = require('jquery'),
    Backbone    = require('backbone'),
    HomeView    = require('app/views/Home'),
    $body = $('body'),
    homeView = new HomeView({el: $body});
...  
return Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "about": "about"
     },

    home: function () {
        homeView.delegateEvents();
        homeView.render();
    },

    about: function () {
        require(["app/views/About"], function (AboutView) {
            var view = new AboutView({el: $body});
            view.render();
        });
    },

...
```

app/router/views/home.js

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
      "click #about": "followAbout"
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(template());
        return this;
    },
    followAbout: function () {
       console.log('about');
       window.router.navigate( "about", { trigger: true } )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you've defined your router like this

```
 var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
     "help":                 "help",    // #help
     "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
     "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
   },
   help: function() {
     ...
   },
   search: function(query, page) {
     ...
   }
 });
```

And then created a new instance of your router

```
router = new Workspace();
Backbone.history.start();
```

In your div you can optionally define your route in a data attribute, which will be convenient for you like this

```
<div id="my_div" data-path="some-url">
  ...
</div>
```

When the user will click the div, you take the route from its data and use `navigate` function to go to that route like this.

```
$("#my_div").on('click', function(e){
  var path = $(this).attr("data-path");
  router.navigate(path, { trigger: true});
  //this will navigate to the path like a single page app without reloading the page
});
```

Checkout backbone [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) for more.

> Edit

```
...
//events inside first view
'click #div-1': 'myFunction'

//myfunction code
myFunction: function(e){
  clicked_div = e.currentTarget;
  path = $(clicked_div).attr('data-path'); //I'm assuming you've stroed the path in your div, or you can get it how ever you like

  window.router.navigate(path, {trigger: true});
  //Also I am assuming you've defined your router under the window object directly, so it can be accessed directly. Or you can always namespace it in an object
  //, to avoid collision
}
```

Comment: I have created router, something similar as in your example, then created two views. First view have div which when clicked should redirect to second view. I have created in first view one event :  `"click #id-1", "function-to-go", and handling event there. Should I handle it in router as in your example? Somehow it is logical to handle it in first view.

Comment: Also, may I mention that when I check network usage in dev tools in chrome, calling `window.location.href = "#some-url"` does not reloads complete page, only the template I have made. Is it possible that backbone overrides default behavior and handles window.location.href without reloads?

Comment: @Izzy can you show your code how you've done? Edit your question and add your codes for it.

Comment: Yes, you put your navigation code inside the `function-to-go`. I'll add an example

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't worked. Then I realized I forgot to include `trigger: true`. Now it works perfectly. I have included stripped source code for future references. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! A few things to note. 1. According to javascript *convention* we capitalize only constructor names. So your method `About` should be `about`. 2. No need to do this `navigate( "#about")`. You can simply pass `"about"` and it should work. Let me know if there is anything.